# Which is the highest priority in PMD?

Tags: pmd

Maybe it's just me, but I can't find information which is the highest priority in [PMD](http://pmd.sf.net): **1** or **5**?

Because of http://pmd.sourceforge.net/running.html and the mention of the command line parameter `-minimumpriority` I think **5** is the highest and **1** is the lowest value. Am I right?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Actually `1` is highest priority and `5` is lowest priority. 

You can check the exported rule set, where

```
<rule ref="rulesets/imports.xml/ImportFromSamePackage"/> <!-- Default -->
<rule ref="rulesets/imports.xml/TooManyStaticImports">
   <priority>5</priority> <!-- Change to priority [information] -->
</rule>
```

The all default rule set configuration is in **pmd-x.x.x.jar\rulesets\*.xml**

[Here](https://pmd.github.io/pmd-5.3.3/customizing/rule-guidelines.html) you can see the rules priority and how they should be used.